# Are high-level consumers garbage collected?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The position of High-level consumers are persisted in Kafka/Zookeeper. Are these ever garbage collected?

Comment: What do you mean by these? The message already consumed?

Comment: No, I mean, if I create a massive amount of high-level consumers over a period of several years, they all store their offset position in Kafka (or Zookeeper, I don't know). Is this automatically garbage collected? Does it matter if it is not?

Answer (score 0):

Consumer offsets are not garbage-collected. They are stored in `__consumer_offsets` in your disk.

For example, Consumer A read a message in Offset 10001. Its offset is stored `__consumer_offsets` and will consume message in Offset 10002 later.